# How to be able to connect a AWS lambda to google adx seller

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a api that i use to get Google Adx seller exchange information. My issue is that i want to put this into a AWS lambda to seed a database everyday automatically, the thing is access tokens expire and once its expired then well i won't have the ability to access the api. I can not make my customers keep having to log back in all the time in order for them to keep getting the adx information. Any suggestions on what I can do would be greatly appreciated. Ill include the script I use but that really shouldn't matter I don't believe.

```
import sys

from apiclient import sample_tools
from oauth2client import client


def main(argv):
 # Authenticate and construct service.
 service, _ = sample_tools.init(
  argv, 'adexchangeseller', 'v2.0', __doc__, __file__,
  scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adexchange.seller.readonly')

try:
# Retrieve report.
result = service.accounts().reports().generate(
    accountId='myaccount',
    startDate='today-6d', endDate='today',
    metric=['AD_REQUESTS', 'CLICKS'],
    dimension=['DATE', 'WINNING_BID_RULE_NAME'],
    sort=['+DATE']).execute()

# Display headers.
for header in result['headers']:
  print '%25s' % header['name'],
print

# Display results.
for row in result['rows']:
  for column in row:
    print '%25s' % column,
  print

# Display totals
for total in result['totals']:
  print '%25s' % total,
print

except client.AccessTokenRefreshError:
  print ('The credentials have been revoked or expired, please re-run 
 the '
       'application to re-authorize')


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(sys.argv)
```

I'm also totally new to python. So this seems like how we want it too. but  I'm waiting on client Adx credentials, so not 100 percent sure. I just wanted to find out about how to get around the token expiring all the time or if someone had suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`google-api-python-client`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/).

When performing server to server interactions with Google's APIs, use  [Service Account Authentication](https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.service_account.html#oauth2client.service_account.ServiceAccountCredentials), this means you don't have to refresh your tokens.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts) is a guide on how to set it up properly.